# Align two elements on the same line using flex: one left and one right

Tags: html, reactjs, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flex to align buttons on the same line : the button "Back" should be at the left and the button "Continue" at the right (end of the line).

```css
.footer {
    display: flex;
}

.back {
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.continue {
    align-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div className={"footer"}>
     <Button className={"back"}> Back </Button>
     <Button className={"continue"} >Continue</Button>
</div>
```

But this is not working, what I am missing ?

Comment: make the footer div the full width of the page  (width: 100%) and then set the CSS style for each button to float: left and float: right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`justify-content: space-between;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) on the flex container to generate the desired layout:

```css
.footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.back {
}

.continue {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div class="footer">
     <Button className={"back"}> Back </Button>
     <Button className={"continue"} >Continue</Button>
</div>
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get `className` to work even with the React imports, so I just changed it to be normal HTML & CSS

Answer (score 2):

The `align-content` property, as well as `align-items` and `align-self`, position flex items along the *cross axis* of the flex container.

With `flex-direction: row` (the default setting in CSS), the cross axis is vertical. So in your code you're attempting to pin the items to the top and the bottom, not the left and right. (Note that the `flex-direction` default in React Native is `column`.)

For *main axis* alignment use the `justify-content` property.

More details here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Answer (score 2):

Use float to align buttons.

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">
     <button class="back">Back</button>
     <button class="continue">Continue</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.back {
   float: left;
}

.continue {
   float: right;
}
```

Comment: The question is about solving the given situation using flex. However, using the css floating properties in your example will make the container (.footer) collapse. You can use the clearfix technic to fix that, but in my humble opinion, flex is way clear and doesn't deliver undesired side effects for this scenario.

Comment: Right, flex property is also a good practice, flex maintain flexible layout with responsiveness.